# How can I update Ruby and Rails on MacOS 10.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, macbook

I just got a Macbook laptop that is running 10.6.3 AKA "Snow Leopard".

I know it comes with Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3, but I was wondering what the best way is to update those to Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and/or [RVM](https://beginrescueend.com/)

RVM allows you tO have several versions of ruby installed if you want.

Homebrew is a nice package manager for Os X.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't update the built-in Ruby. Apple put it there for their use. If you want to piggy-back on it without changes, that's fine. If you make changes you run the risk of affecting apps that expect it to be at the standard Apple-installation version.

Instead, I recommend [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) for installing a separate version of Ruby for your own use. RVM makes it easy to manage and works very well. I have it on my personal laptop, my work Mac Pro, and a bunch of Linux machines.

Once you have a Ruby installed under RVM's control you can install, update and delete gems without affecting the built-in Ruby. You can install multiple versions of Ruby and of gemsets, switching back and forth quickly and easily.